# does not have a public property named 'Text'

Tags: asp.net

This is my Code:

```
 <asp:MultiView ID="mltvAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' />
```

This is my Error:

`Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.MultiView' does not have a public property named 'Text'.`

Comment: What are you trying to do? The error is clear as water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error message because there is no such property like `Text` in `MultiView` control. Actually, MultiView acts as a container for other control and mark-ups according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227665(v=vs.100).aspx).

I don't know what your requirment is but if have to use MultiView, then add controls inside it, something like this:-

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Comment: @vicky - You are welcome :) If that answered your question you can mark it as answer to appreciate some1 here on SO. Read this small article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers